# Dynamic border length on css nav menu

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to style my navigation bar so that the selected link has a border underneath it, each link in the nav bar has the same width of 120px but the text for each link is of different lengths, e.g. Home, Client Area, FAQ etc. What I'm trying to do is make it so that the bottom border is only the length of the text and not the length of the whole `a` element which all have a width of 120px. I hope I've explained it alright.

Below is the code I'm using.

HTML Code

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="About.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Client Area</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS Code

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
}

nav li {
    float:left;
}

nav {
    float:right;
    margin-top: -3%;
}

nav a {
    display:block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#134BA0;
    font-size: 22px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color:#387CE1;
}

a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom: #387CE1 solid 2px;
}
```

On the `a.active` class I tried things like `width:100%;` `border-width: 100%;` and `a.active border {width;100%;}`. However none of these worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the css for "nav a" by removing the width and instead give margin, like this:-

```
nav a {
display: block;
margin: 0 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #134BA0;
font-size: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
}

nav li {
    float:left;
    width: 120px;
}

nav {
    float:right;
    margin-top: -3%;
}

nav li a {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#134BA0;
    font-size: 22px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color:#387CE1;
}

nav li a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom: #387CE1 solid 2px;
}
```

> Basically i put the width on the li and remove the display block on the a